# Webscraping with BeautifulSoup FindAll

Tags: python, web-scraping, findall

I want to download the hrefs of the 4 articles right above NEED TO KNOW on the following website:

http://www.marketwatch.com/

but I cannot identify them uniquely with FindAll. The following approaches give me the articles, but also a bunch of others, that also fit those criteria.

```
trend_articles  = soup1.findAll("a", {"class": "link"})
href= article.a["href"]

trend_articles  = soup1.findAll("div", {"class": "content--secondary"})
href= article.a["href"]
```

Does someone have a suggestion, how I can get those 4, and only those 4 articles?

Comment: I found one possible path that would begin at the top at:trend_articles  = soup1.findAll("div", {"class": "element2 element--article is-lead "}) and then use href= article.div.div.ul.li.a["href"] but this leads me into the first ul but I need to get into the second ul.

Comment: Basically, if I could navigate along the tree, that would be helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems works for me:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

page = requests.get("http://www.marketwatch.com/").content
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'lxml')
header_secondare = soup.find('header', {'class': 'header--secondary'})
trend_articles = header_secondare.find_next_siblings('div', {'class': 'group group--list '})[0].findAll('a')

trend_articles = [article.contents[0] for article in trend_articles]
print(trend_articles)
```

Comment: Woow, that looks a lot simpler than what I was trying to do. Thank you so much!!!

Comment: @Niccola Tartaglia You are welcome! Good luck to you!